# I just uninstalled ros because of some error and i want to install it again> Need Help!

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory

I am getting this errror in terminal and i am not able to install ros again! Can somebody please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250474/i-just-uninstalled-ros-because-of-some-error-and-i-want-to-install-it-again%3E-need-help!/) by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on 2016-12-20**:
I have done all the ROS uninstallation steps properly.. Still i am facing the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably still sourcing this file in your bashrc. (Do you still have something like "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" in your ~/.bashrc?)

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2016-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on 2016-12-21**:
yeah! problem solved
thanks alot